# When I reduce header size in Word all hell breaks loose

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, headers

I am using Microsoft Word 2007 and suddenly noticed that the height of the headers was really large -- a few cm.  The only way I could change the height was to drag the bottom margin up on the left hand side.  But when I do this and release the mouse, very weird things happen.  The header seems to merge with the footer above and the text in the document is greyed out and I can't select non-header/footer text any more.

I can revert by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but I still need to reduce these header sizes. How can I do this?

(The document is largish -- but only 45 pages.)

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Keep in mind software recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Actually ignore me.  The problem was loads of spaces and carriage returns in the header.  When I removed these, the header was no longer huge.  I though it was the size of the header setting.  But actually it was contents of the header I couldn't see.